# JSON To Pandas Dataframe with incomplete JSON Properties

Tags: python, json, pandas

Let's say I have a JSON as such:

```json
[
    {
        name: "user1",
        age: 12,
        category: "young",
    },
    {
        name: "user2",
        category: "old",
    },
    {
        name: "user3",
        age: 23,
    }
]
```

As we can see `user1` has the most complete properties which are `name, age, category` while `user2` only has `name, category` and `user3` only has `name, age`. How can I convert this to a dataframe where the expected result is as such:

| id | name | age | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 12 | young |
| 2 | user2 | null | old |
| 3 | user3 | 23 | null |

Hence leaving the empty property as `null`.

**Note that every user can have their JSON property in different position. For example `user4` might have properties in the order of `name, age, category` while `user5` might have properties in the order of `age, name, category`**

Answer (score 3):

If convert json to list of dictionaries pandas add missing values for missing categories:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as f:    
    data = json.load(f)  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.insert(0, 'id', range(1, len(df)+1))
print (df) 
   id   name   age category
0   1  user1  12.0    young
1   2  user2   NaN      old
2   3  user3  23.0      NaN
```